# Jquery .append and links

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function (data) {
    var json = data;

    if (json["type"] == "story") {
        $(".title").append("<p><a href=" + json["url"] + ">" + json["title"] + "</a> " + json["id"] + "</p>");
    }
}
```

when i do this what i want to get is something like

```
<p><a href="http://www.vanityfair.com/business/2014/11/satya-nadella-bill-gates-steve-ballmer-microsoft.print">The Microsoft Empire Reboots</a> 8441095</p>
```

but in some cases i get

```
<p><a href="https://firstlook.org/theintercept/2014/10/10/core-secrets"></a>Core Secrets: NSA Saboteurs in China and Germany 8441055</p>
```

the .json is from: https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8441055.json?print=pretty

```
{
  "by" : "patrickgokey",
  "id" : 8441055,
  "kids" : [ 8441399, 8441097, 8441985, 8441301, 8441852, 8441578, 8441287, 8441389, 8441586, 8441583, 8441584, 8441449, 8441380 ],
  "score" : 161,
  "text" : "",
  "time" : 1412995787,
  "title" : "Core Secrets: NSA Saboteurs in China and Germany",
  "type" : "story",
  "url" : "https://firstlook.org/theintercept/2014/10/10/core-secrets/"
}
```

Is this caused by an error in the .append function?

Comment: it depends on your json data

Comment: You need to show the data that causes the problem so that we can replicate it.

Comment: That does seem to be accurate: http://jsfiddle.net/pjammox5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes on the `href` attribute:

```
if (json["type"] == "story") {
    $(".title").append("<p><a href='" + json["url"] + "'>" + json["title"] + "</a> " + json["id"] + "</p>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pjammox5/1/

To see why, look at the difference in URLs:

> http://www.vanityfair.com/business/2014/11/satya-nadella-bill-gates-steve-ballmer-microsoft.print
>   https://firstlook.org/theintercept/2014/10/10/core-secrets/

Note the end of the second, `-secrets/`, combines with the `<a href=>` to be self-closing:

```
<a href=https://firstlook.org/theintercept/2014/10/10/core-secrets/> <--Closes the tag
```